# Error executing: pip install opencv-python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, pip

So im trying to install OpenCV-Python using my administrator command prompt in windows 10 and my version of python is 3.9 and pip is fully updated.. here is the (massive) error I get after trying to execute `pip install opencv-python`

This is what happens:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>pip install opencv-python
Collecting opencv-python
  Using cached opencv-python-4.4.0.44.tar.gz (88.9 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' 'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.240.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prbqcb63\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel scikit-build cmake pip 'numpy==1.11.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (310 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7"' don't match your environment
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached setuptools-50.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)
  Collecting scikit-build
    Using cached scikit_build-0.11.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (72 kB)
  Collecting cmake
    Using cached cmake-3.18.2.post1-py3-none-win_amd64.whl (34.7 MB)
  Collecting pip
    Using cached pip-20.2.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
  Collecting numpy==1.17.3
    Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)
  Collecting distro
    Using cached distro-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (18 kB)
  Collecting packaging
    Using cached packaging-20.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
  Collecting six
    Using cached six-1.15.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
  Collecting pyparsing>=2.0.2
    Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
  Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
  Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, distro, six, pyparsing, packaging, scikit-build, cmake, pip, numpy
      Running setup.py install for numpy: started
      Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\inbet\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dqkz6qyf\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\inbet\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-dqkz6qyf\\numpy\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zko205u_\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prbqcb63\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-prbqcb63\overlay\Include\numpy'
           cwd: C:\Users\inbet\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-dqkz6qyf\numpy\
      Complete output (277 lines):
      Running from numpy source directory.
```

There is a LOT more after that but I am unable to post the error in its entirety as it says "it looks like your post is mostly code. please add some more details"

My gut feeling is that all of this is occurring because my python directory isn't in `C:\ProgramFiles\Python` or maybe it has to do with the fact that I installed python via the windows app store.

I know its a lot of code and I am literally just beginning to get into this because I am trying to create a script that will scrape eBay thumbnails and download the images from a start page with search terms entered, if and only if those images contain numbers. Hence why I am trying to install OpenCV.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. The last time I ever coded anything was when I was 12 years old playing Never Winter Nights which used something like C+ so I generally know my way around under the hood but am totally new to python specific commands and am hoping this little project I am attempting will teach me a useful amount about python and also automate this whole "needle in a haystack" search for images with numbers in them.

Cheers

Comment: Hi, Could you find any solution? I am also facing the exact issue.

Answer (score 0):

opencv require install wheel before that